# How can I authenticate users using google OIDC with Spring Security 5.1+

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security, openid-connect

[I found this](https://dzone.com/articles/getting-started-with-google-sign-in-in-spring-boot) however oauth as client doesn't work exactly the same in Spring Boot 2.1/Security 5.1, as far as I know Oauth no longer requires an additional module. I was able to do facebook/okta login without the Oauth2 module, and got close with Google; this is the config for google I came up with.

```
spring.security.oauth2.client.registration.google.client-id=10240000000-k88NNNNNNN.apps.googleusercontent.com
spring.security.oauth2.client.registration.google.client-secret=fsjflsajfldajflsajf
spring.security.oauth2.client.registration.google.redirect-uri=http://localhost:8080/login/oauth2/code/google
spring.security.oauth2.client.provider.google.token-uri=https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v3/token
spring.security.oauth2.client.provider.google.authorization-uri=https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/v2/auth
```

and this proof of concept controller, which shouldn't need changing (though examples can be in Java)

```
@RestController
class MainController {

    private val log: Logger = LogManager.getLogger(this::class.java)

    @GetMapping
    fun index(details: Authentication): String {
        log.info("{}", details)
        return "Hello, ${details.name}"
    }
}
```

I end up with some stacktraces and redirect loops. What more do I need to do to make Authentication with Google work?

**I would prefer an answer that describes how to set all of the application properties and not simply address my single stacktrace.**

*stacktrace*

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unable to convert claim 'iss' to URL: no protocol: accounts.google.com
    at org.springframework.security.oauth2.core.ClaimAccessor.getClaimAsURL(ClaimAccessor.java:118) ~[spring-security-oauth2-core-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.oauth2.core.oidc.IdTokenClaimAccessor.getIssuer(IdTokenClaimAccessor.java:46) ~[spring-security-oauth2-core-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.oidc.authentication.OidcTokenValidator.validateIdToken(OidcTokenValidator.java:41) ~[spring-security-oauth2-client-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.oidc.authentication.OidcAuthorizationCodeAuthenticationProvider.createOidcToken(OidcAuthorizationCodeAuthenticationProvider.java:196) ~[spring-security-oauth2-client-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.oidc.authentication.OidcAuthorizationCodeAuthenticationProvider.authenticate(OidcAuthorizationCodeAuthenticationProvider.java:156) ~[spring-security-oauth2-client-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.authentication.ProviderManager.authenticate(ProviderManager.java:175) ~[spring-security-core-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.web.OAuth2LoginAuthenticationFilter.attemptAuthentication(OAuth2LoginAuthenticationFilter.java:186) ~[spring-security-oauth2-client-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:212) ~[spring-security-web-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.web.OAuth2AuthorizationRequestRedirectFilter.doFilterInternal(OAuth2AuthorizationRequestRedirectFilter.java:160) ~[spring-security-oauth2-client-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.web.OAuth2AuthorizationRequestRedirectFilter.doFilterInternal(OAuth2AuthorizationRequestRedirectFilter.java:160) ~[spring-security-oauth2-client-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:116) ~[spring-security-web-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.csrf.CsrfFilter.doFilterInternal(CsrfFilter.java:100) ~[spring-security-web-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doFilterInternal(HeaderWriterFilter.java:74) ~[spring-security-web-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:105) ~[spring-security-web-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:56) ~[spring-security-web-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:215) ~[spring-security-web-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:178) ~[spring-security-web-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:357) ~[spring-web-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:270) ~[spring-web-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.14.jar:9.0.14]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.14.jar:9.0.14]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:99) ~[spring-web-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.14.jar:9.0.14]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.14.jar:9.0.14]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:92) ~[spring-web-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.14.jar:9.0.14]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.14.jar:9.0.14]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:93) ~[spring-web-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.14.jar:9.0.14]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.14.jar:9.0.14]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:200) ~[spring-web-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.14.jar:9.0.14]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.14.jar:9.0.14]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:199) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.14.jar:9.0.14]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.14.jar:9.0.14]
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:490) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.14.jar:9.0.14]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:139) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.14.jar:9.0.14]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.14.jar:9.0.14]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:74) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.14.jar:9.0.14]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.14.jar:9.0.14]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:408) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.14.jar:9.0.14]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.14.jar:9.0.14]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:834) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.14.jar:9.0.14]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1417) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.14.jar:9.0.14]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.14.jar:9.0.14]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628) ~[na:na]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.14.jar:9.0.14]
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834) ~[na:na]
Caused by: java.net.MalformedURLException: no protocol: accounts.google.com
    at java.base/java.net.URL.<init>(URL.java:627) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.net.URL.<init>(URL.java:523) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.net.URL.<init>(URL.java:470) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.security.oauth2.core.ClaimAccessor.getClaimAsURL(ClaimAccessor.java:116) ~[spring-security-oauth2-core-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
    ... 65 common frames omitted
```

Comment: Can you show complete stacktrace?

Comment: @Bsquare added stacktrace

Comment: You could change the default validators to validate the ISS as `accounts.google.com`

Comment: the second stacktrace: probably you have version conflicts in your dependencies.

Comment: @stacker I'll check to make sure something screwy isn't going on... but since I'm using the BOM... unless there's a bug in gradle's enforcePlatform (or whatever) (and by bug I mean still doesn't work the way maven does)

Comment: @xenoterracide i don't think so, do you have a default no-args constructor in your UserDetails class?

Comment: @stacker it's whatever Spring Security provides, literally the only 2 classes I've defined are the controller here, and a boilerplate `SpringBootApplication`, worked without incident for Spring Boot 2.1.1 with facebook.... so unless there's a regression with that in Spring Security.

Comment: the exception wasn't from spring security, it was from spring mvc. it tries to pass UserDetails object to index(details: UserDetails) by creating one, but it couldn't find a non-args constructor because it's an interface. you can get UserDetails using the SecurityContextHolder if that's what you want

Comment: @stacker you can inject into request methods now... this was working... hmm... well it blows up on that with okta now too so... I'm going to try to build a reproducible sample, and see if it's different between 2.1.1 and 2.1.2, because that was working.

Comment: @stacker other problem was *must be an implementation of* `Principal/Authentication` which has `UserDetails` changed it thinking it would work.

Comment: @xenoterracide I didn't understand, can you elaborate more?

Comment: @stacker updated my controller code, but it's also seen here in section 3 https://www.baeldung.com/get-user-in-spring-security for some reason I thought you could do it with UserDetails as well.

Comment: @xenoterracide it depends on what security workflow you are using because it will effect what's in  SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().${details.name} should not work in your case can you try with ((OAuth2AuthenticationToken )details).getAuthorizedClientRegistrationId ()?

Comment: Name actually works but it's not a human name it's more like the client ID or something. Either way I got that that injection working...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

the problem is that in the token verification step the issuer is `accounts.google.com` but spring expects it to be `https://accounts.google.com`.

I have a similar app, and I tested it with your `token-uri`, the "`iss`" was "`accounts.google.com`" (and many redirects). so I changed the `token-uri` to `https://oauth2.googleapis.com/token` (which is the latest) and it returns "`iss`": "https://accounts.google.com".

have a look at the latest [endpoints](https://accounts.google.com/.well-known/openid-configuration) supported by Google.

I couldn't find any google docs that explain these changes except [Here](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OpenIDConnect):

> Verify that the value of iss in the ID token is equal to
>   https://accounts.google.com or accounts.google.com.

without elaborating both the two cases.

Answer (score 0):

I recently developed code for authentication with google using OAuth2. You can refer to the same at - [ssousinggoogle](https://github.com/vikash100dhn/ssousinggoogle.git)
Hope it helps!

Let me know if you face any issue.

Also, can you try changing the url to  -

can you try with changing **spring.security.oauth2.client.provider.google.authorization-uri** to **https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth**