# How do I enable Auth0 OIDC login with Spring Security 5.1+

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, auth0

Spring 5.1+ should allow me to configure Auth0's login without a 3rd party jar, [I've done similar things before](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54121405/206466). problem is I haven't figured out all the right properties. What do I need to set in order for this to work?

Comment: Did you take a look at the documentation https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/html5/#oauth2client I did the same thing a while ago to secure a Spring Boot Admin server with Spring Security 5 + Keycloak

Comment: @akuma8 yeah, I'm just trying to figure out the values that need to be set for Auth0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a new Application in Auth0 Dashboard, select Spring Boot as framework.

Set the following callback URL, when adding the settings of your application.

```
http://localhost:8080/login/oauth2/code/auth0
```

In dependencies

```kotlin
  runtimeOnly("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-security")
  runtimeOnly("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web")
  runtimeOnly("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-oauth2-client")
```

In `application.properties` is

```
spring.security.oauth2.client.registration.auth0.scope[0]=openid
spring.security.oauth2.client.registration.auth0.scope[1]=profile
spring.security.oauth2.client.registration.auth0.scope[2]=email
spring.security.oauth2.client.registration.auth0.client-id=<your client id in your application in Auth0 Dashboard>
spring.security.oauth2.client.registration.auth0.client-secret=<your secret in your application in Auth0 Dashboard>
# I haven't found general documentation for this but it's in format https://<your domain in dashboard
spring.security.oauth2.client.provider.auth0.issuer-uri=https://<your domain in your application in Auth0 Dashboard>
```

For more information a technology documentation page should have opened up when you created the application. Seems to be available via Applicaton -> QuickStart.

Comment: Have you managed to get this to work for custom scopes? I am struggling!